# `retrieve-marker` in attribute value

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to use a marker to determine the image to show in a header/footer.  Each chapter has a marker which communicates the image to use.  When I use `<fo:marker` / `<fo:retreive-marker` in an `<xsl:attribute` element, it understandably produces an invalid `src=` value.

e.g. pages:

1. Chapter 1
2. Chapter 1 ends; chapter 2 begins
3. Chapter 2

Header for page 1 and 2 would reference `<external-graphic src="1.png"/>` and 3 would reference `<external-graphic src="2.png"/>`.

How can I embed an image in a header or footer that varies based on the flow content?

Comment: Can you show an example of the XSL-FO markup that isn't working for you, and the XSLT that produces it? You can't put an element inside an attribute in XML, but it's hard to tell you what to fix when we don't know what you're doing now.

Comment: @TonyGraham, the intent is to vary an image based on a marker. I’m currently doing `<fo:external-graphic><xsl:attribute name=“src”><fo:marker…`. I understand why that doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `fo:marker` could contain just text, but you can't retrieve that text to make the value of a `src` property.

What would work is to retrieve an entire `fo:external-graphic` that has the correct `src` value.  Something like (untested):

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="...">
  <fo:marker marker-class-name="image">
    <fo:external-graphic src="1.png"/>
  </fo:marker>
  <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl:region-after">
    <fo:block><fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="image"/></fo:block>
  </fo:static-content>
  <!-- Stuff -->
</fo:page-sequence>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="...">
  <fo:marker marker-class-name="image">
    <fo:external-graphic src="2.png"/>
  </fo:marker>
  <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl:region-after">
    <fo:block><fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="image"/></fo:block>
  </fo:static-content>
  <!-- More stuff -->
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the entire image in the marker, not just the URL.